# How I will log in in pentaho data integration after installation on windows

Tags: pdi

I have installed pentaho data integration. I don't know from where I will take start, I mean where I should click to run the application in the installed folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the installation folder you can run the spoon.bat file which will launch the application. It will then ask you to select a repository, which you can then select by browsing to the folder you wish to use as your repository, or press cancel to skip that step and not use a repository.